# I am newbie to php, i would like to solve with matrix type of arrays for the followings

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

Here is the csv format:

```
ServerA,OK,app1
ServerB,OK,app2
ServerC,OK,app3
ServerD,,app4
ServerA,OK,app2
ServerB,,app3
ServerC,OK,app1
ServerD,OK,app2
ServerA,OK,app3
ServerB,OK,app1
ServerC,,app2
```

What I would like is to display:

```
Server:     App1:     App2:  App3:  App4
ServerA      OK        OK     OK     OK
SERverB      OK        OK     N/A    OK
```

If second field is empty display N/A.

This is what I tried:

```
$file = "serverdata.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "r") or die("Can't open file serverdata.txt");


while(!feof($fp)) {
    $data = fgets($fp, 1024);
    $navData = explode(',',$data);

            $host = $navData[0];
            $app = $navData[2];
            $status = $navData[1];
            $myData[$host][$app] = $status;


}


foreach ($myData as $tempHost) {
if (isset($myData[$tempHost]['app1'])) {
          $App1_status =  $mydata[$tempHost]['app1'];
    }
    else {
           $App1_status = "N/A";
    }

.
.
.
.
<same for all other apps status >

print "<TD>$tempHost</TD><TD>$App1_status</TD><TD>$App2_status</TD><TD>$App3_status</TD>  <TD>$App4_status</TD></TR>\n";
}


}
```

Dont seem to get it work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may be better off with `fgetcsv` than with `fgets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename = 'serverdata.txt';
$data_lines = file($filename);
$server_app_data = array();
$servers = array();
$apps = array();
foreach($data_lines as $line) {
  list($server,$status,$app) = explode(',',$line);
  $server_app_data[$server][$app] = $status;
  if(!in_array($server, $servers)) $servers[] = $server;
  if(!in_array($app, $apps)) $apps[] = $app;
}

$table_content = '<table><thead><tr><th>Server:</th>';
foreach($apps as $app) $table_content .= '<th>'.ucwords(trim($app)).':</th>';
$table_content .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
foreach($servers as $server) {
  $table_content .= '<tr><th>'.$server.'</th>';
  foreach($apps as $app) {
    $table_content .= '<td>'.($server_app_data[$server][$app]?:'N/A').'</td>';
  }
  $table_content .= '</tr>';
}
$table_content .= '</table>';

echo $table_content;
```

produces the following table:

```
Server:     App1:   App2:   App3:   App4:
ServerA     OK      OK      OK      N/A
ServerB     OK      OK      N/A     N/A
ServerC     OK      N/A     OK      N/A
ServerD     N/A     OK      N/A     N/A
```

Answer (score 3):

You have basically two parts in your application. The first part is to read in the file and store the data in memory. You actually did this pretty well I'm mainly only using different variable names in my example and I'm making use of the `SplFileObject` because it already parses the comma separated values for us:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('serverdata.txt');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$hosts = array();
$apps = array();
foreach($file as $line) {
    list($host, $status, $app) = $line;
    $apps[$app] = 1;
    $hosts[$host][$app] = $status;
}
```

Each line is parsed into `$host`, `$status` and `$app`. I save the main data as you did (here into `$hosts`). I also save the app names into another array called `$apps` so that it is possible later on to build a matrix based on hosts *and* apps. I save the application names as keys which is a simple way to remove duplicates because in an array each key can only exists once.

The second part then is to output the data. I do it here in plain text, if you need that with HTML it probably is even more easy:

```
echo "+----------+", str_repeat('------+', count($apps)), "\n";
echo "| Server   |";
foreach($apps as $name => $v) {
    echo " $name |";
}
echo "\n", "+----------+", str_repeat('------+', count($apps)), "\n";

foreach($hosts as $host => $hostApps) {
    printf("| %' -8s |", $host);
    foreach($apps as $name => $v) {
        $value = isset($hostApps[$name]) ? $hostApps[$name] : "N/A";
        printf("  %' -3s |", $value);
    }
    echo "\n", "+----------+", str_repeat('------+', count($apps)), "\n";
}
```

As you can see there is one `foreach` inside the other. One is for all hosts, the other is for all apps.

This will then create the output for the data you have provided for `serverdata.txt`:

```
+----------+------+------+------+------+
| Server   | app1 | app2 | app3 | app4 |
+----------+------+------+------+------+
| ServerA  |  OK  |  OK  |  OK  |  N/A |
+----------+------+------+------+------+
| ServerB  |  OK  |  OK  |      |  N/A |
+----------+------+------+------+------+
| ServerC  |  OK  |      |  OK  |  N/A |
+----------+------+------+------+------+
| ServerD  |  N/A |  OK  |  N/A |      |
+----------+------+------+------+------+
```

I hope this example is helpful. You can do a third step as well, before you output the data, to normalize the array so that each host (row) has the data for all apps already. Doing output then is even more easy. But I leave that for an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The line `foreach ($myData as $tempHost)` will store an array in `$tempHost`.  What you want is `foreach ($myData as $tempHost=>$hostData)` (then you can replace all instances of `$myData[$tempHost]` with `$hostData`).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($myData as $host=>$apps) {
print "<TD>$host</TD>";
foreach($apps as $status)
    print "<TD>".($status!=""?$status:"N/A")."</TD>";
}
print "\n";
```

Comment: try running it and you'll see

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. I will try it out and see how it goes.